# 'figurescaption.sty' not found

Tags: floats, packages

I'm using a package from a website, with part of codelist is as follow.

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn]{article}  
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\linespread{1.05}  
\usepackage{microtype}  
\usepackage[bahasa]{babel}  
\usepackage[left=3.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.50cm,columnsep=0.5cm]{geometry}  
\usepackage[hang, small,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{figurescaption} %   
\usepackage{booktabs}  
\usepackage{enumitem}  
\usepackage{blindtext}  
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep}  
\usepackage{abstract}  
\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\bfseries}  
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont\small\itshape}  
\usepackage{titlesec}  
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}  
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\roman{subsection}}     
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\scshape\centering}{\thesection.}{1em}{}  
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\large}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{}   
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   
\pagestyle{fancy}  
\fancyhead{}  
\fancyfoot{} 
\fancyhead[C]{Jurnal KIP $\bullet$ May 2017 $\bullet$ Vol. IV, No. 3}  
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}  
\usepackage{titling}  
\usepackage{hyperref}  
\setlength{\droptitle}{-4\baselineskip}
\pretitle{\begin{center}\Large\bfseries} 
\posttitle{\end{center}} 
\title{Judul Artikel}    
\author{%
\textsc{The writer} \\[1ex]  
\normalsize My University \\  
\normalsize \href{mailto:me@mymail.com}{me@mymail.com}  
}
\date{} 
\renewcommand{\maketitlehookd}{
\begin{abstract}
\noindent \blindtext
\end{abstract}
}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Pendahuluan}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

but, I have the Error message: *figurecscaption.sty* not found in the package.
Please help how to fix the code.

Comment: Try to replace `figurescaption` by `caption`.

Comment: In case this is your real email address, you may want to remove it from your questions - makes life for your spam filter easier.

Comment: I've never heard of such a package.

Comment: Does the suggestion of TeXnician solve your problem?

Comment: yup. it is well.

Comment: @TeXnician Do you ant to write up an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use a package that doesn't exist. In your case `figurescaption.sty` can't be found, because it is not available in a TeX distribution. You should use `caption` instead, which takes this type of arguments (btw please enclose multiple options in braces).

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn]{article}  
\usepackage[bahasa]{babel}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm,columnsep=0.5cm]{geometry}  
\usepackage[hang, small,labelfont={bf,up},textfont={it,up}]{caption} %   

\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{microtype}  

\usepackage{blindtext}  
\usepackage{booktabs}  
\usepackage{enumitem}  
\usepackage{abstract}  
\usepackage{titlesec}  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   
\usepackage{titling}  
\usepackage{hyperref}  

\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep}  
\linespread{1.05}  

\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\bfseries}  
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont\small\itshape}  

\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}  
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\roman{subsection}}     
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\scshape\centering}{\thesection.}{1em}{}  
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\large}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{}   

\pagestyle{fancy}  
\fancyhead{}  
\fancyfoot{} 
\fancyhead[C]{Jurnal KIP $\bullet$ May 2017 $\bullet$ Vol. IV, No. 3}  
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}  

\setlength{\droptitle}{-4\baselineskip}
\pretitle{\begin{center}\Large\bfseries} 
\posttitle{\end{center}} 

\renewcommand{\maketitlehookd}{
\begin{abstract}
\noindent \blindtext
\end{abstract}
}

\title{Judul Artikel}    
\author{%
\textsc{The writer} \\[1ex]  
\normalsize My University \\  
\normalsize \href{mailto:me@mymail.com}{me@mymail.com}  
}
\date{} 
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Pendahuluan}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you, @TeXnician, this problem was solved on the day asked.

Comment: @EnosLolang Yes, but the usual standard here is to answer a question in order to solve it. Usually the asking person expects a real answer and can upvote and accept it, if it solves the problem.